# Having trouble getting DIV contents to align to the bottom of the DIV

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have some navigation links that I would like to align to the right and bottom of my header.  The contents are

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="/dashboard">My Subscriptions</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
            <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
          </ul>
```

and the style I’m applying is

```
header ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin-right: 15px;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}
```

Although these line up to the right ok, they do not align to the bottom of the div — https://jsfiddle.net/cujz8tye/ .  What am I missing?

Comment: `vertical-align` does not work when you *float* them...

Comment: Good to know.  what does?

Comment: where is your header tag?please edit the question

Comment: can you an image of what you want to achieve?

Comment: `vertical-align` is for tables, not div elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flexbox to align vertically items in a simpler way.

Here's an **[updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cujz8tye/2/)**

Relevant modifications: list isn't floating anymore and:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between; /* The 2 flex items a#logo and nav will be aligned leftmost and rightmost */
  height: 100%; /* flex container will occupy the full height of its parent (73px) */
}
.container > nav {
  align-self: flex-end; /* this flex item (nav children of .container, not ul directly) will align itself vertically at the bottom. */
                        /*  Because the flex container is by default flex-direction: row thus align-self is for the other axis, vertical */
}
```

edit: use Autoprefixer (if it isn't already the case) to be compatible with IE10+. It'll take care of adding for you the required prefixes for all 3 versions of the flexbox syntax ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use **CSS Flexbox**. **[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cujz8tye/5/)**.

Wrap everything inside the container under `.content-holder` like:

```
<div class="content-holder">
  <a id="logo" href="#">sample app</a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="/dashboard">My Subscriptions</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
      <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Then, apply the CSS:

```
.content-holder {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

nav ul {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Have a look at the working snippet below:

```css
header {
  box-shadow: none;
  background: #44505d;
  border-bottom: none;
  height: 73px;
}

#branding {
  height: 60px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100001;
}

.content-holder {
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}    

header ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

header ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  padding-top: 73px;
  line-height: 1.4;
  font-family: "Karla", "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
}

a, .clickable {
  color: #53a3c2;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="branding" class="clearFix">
  <div class="container clearFix">
    <div class="content-holder">
      <a id="logo" href="#">sample app</a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="/dashboard">My Subscriptions</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
          <li><a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/logout">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but when I look at your Fiddle the contents of the nav div are centered and not aligned to the bottom.  How do i aligin them to the bottom?

Comment: @Natalia Oh! My bad. Please have a look I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
header {
    height:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

Replace 40px with the height of the header.  This forces vertical-align to work in some cases.